# Discount Code applying to more than the one specified price field

Tags: cividiscount

I have multiple discount codes set up for my event fees. One of which is applying a fixed amount I specified for only one price field to two fields instead. It's the only code misbehaving. It essentially applies the same dollar amount discount to a price field I didn't include in the code set up. I've tried recreating the code with another name, and changing the fee amount for one (since both fields are the same price?). Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This may help, perhaps?

https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/cividiscount/-/issues/295#note_87867

It does not solve the issue when two discounts are applied to two different price field options or even two different price fields on the same price set. If this is not an issue for you, the above patch should work.